# Using anonymous functions with lapply/sapply in R?

Tags: r, lapply, anonymous-function, sapply

I'm trying to use sapply to take each item in a list (e.g. "Golf","Malibu","Corvette") and create a new list with the highest value in the dataframe that list was split from (e.g. cars$sale_price). I'm trying to use an anonymous function to do so, but I can't get that function to work.

The basic issue here is that I'm not very good at writing functions.

First, I took the original dataframe **cars** and used `split` to create a list of unique car names - I called this **car_names**.

Now, I'm trying to create a new list, using sapply, of the highest sale price of each type of car in the list. I'm sure I'm starting the thing correctly ...

```
price_list <- sapply(car_names,
```

... but I can't for the life of me get an anonymous function to simply apply `max` to all instances of each car name in cars$sale price.

I've tried a bunch of stuff, all of which has returned an error. Here's an example:

```
price_list <- sapply(car_names, function(x) {
    max(cars$saleprice[x])
})
```

Which returns:

```
Error in h115$nominate_dim1[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I'm sure this is trivially simply for even moderate experienced programmers, but I'm ... not one of those! I suspect that I'm pointing to something incorrectly, but I can't get past it. Any ideas?

---

Edit: Here's a reproducible example.

First, the "source" dataframe:

```
cars1 <- data.frame("car_names" = c("Corvette", "Corvette", "Corvette", "Golf", "Golf", "Golf", "Malibu", "Malibu", "Malibu"),"saleprice" = c(32000,45000,72000,7500,16000,22000,33000,21000,26500))
```

Next, splitting the df by car_names:

```
cars1_split <- split(cars1, cars1$car_names)
```

Now, attempting to pass `max` to `sapply` and getting an error:

```
maxes <- sapply(cars1_split, function(x){
  max(cars1$saleprice[x])
})
```

Hopefully this give you guys something to work with!

Comment: I think the problem is that each element in 'car_names' is a list. If x is a list, max(cars$saleprice[x]) would result in an error. I think that's why you are getting an error, but won't know for sure unless you post a reproducible example.

Comment: You should share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show expected output.

Comment: You guys are right, @markus and @David-Rosenman! Thanks for the feedback. I have a busy hour or two but will share a simple reproducible example shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here, let's start with `aggregate` - not what you asked for but I want to keep your attention high ;)

```
aggregate(saleprice ~ car_names, cars1, max)
#  car_names saleprice
#1  Corvette     72000
#2      Golf     22000
#3    Malibu     33000
```

Returns a data.frame (which you can easily `split` if you need a list)

`aggregate` is similar to `tapply` coming next

```
tapply(cars1$saleprice, cars1$car_names, FUN = max)
#Corvette     Golf   Malibu 
#   72000    22000    33000
```

Or try `by` and `which.max`

```
by(cars1, cars1$car_names, FUN = function(x) x[which.max(x$saleprice), ])
#cars1$car_names: Corvette
#  car_names saleprice
#3  Corvette     72000
#-------------------------------
#cars1$car_names: Golf
#  car_names saleprice
#6      Golf     22000
#-------------------------------
#cars1$car_names: Malibu
#  car_names saleprice
#7    Malibu     33000
```

Finally, you can use also `lapply` and `split` (for which `by` is somewhat shorthand)

```
lapply(split(cars1, cars1$car_names), function(x) x[which.max(x$saleprice), ])
#$Corvette
#  car_names saleprice
#3  Corvette     72000

#$Golf
#  car_names saleprice
#6      Golf     22000

#$Malibu
#  car_names saleprice
#7    Malibu     33000
```

Comment: Man, this is great. ````aggregate```` is so much cleaner!

Comment: Followup: if I wanted to do ````lapply```` , as in your last example, but now I wanted to calculate mean sales prices instead of maxes, how would I do that? There isn't a which.mean, as far as I can tell, and replacing ````which.max```` with ````mean```` gives me a messed-up matrix.

Comment: @logjammin Sorry for the delay, you would need to do `lapply(split(cars1, cars1$car_names), function(x) mean(x$saleprice))`. But you are better off using `aggregate` here.